# В node js, с точки зрения производительности, лучше использовать синхронные функции или асинхронные?

Tags: node.js, async-await

Вот, например, есть две функции:

1)

```
fs.existsSync();
```

2. 

```
fs.exists();
```

Вот, проверяем наличие файла, какая разница - синхронно или асинхронно, ведь все равно это зависит от жесткого диска и т.д.

А функции так и так придется ждать, пока не придет результат, в чем подвох?

Comment: Да вроде бы работает, эта функция из: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: дело тут не в производительности. вернее не так. если тебе важно как можно быстрее выполнить эту "операцию" и плевать на всё остальное и твоё "плевать" очень-очень-очень обосновано - нужно брать existsSync. если нет опыта или уверенности в том обосновано ли это - 25 раз прочитать https://nodejs.org/ru/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/, поспать, потом прочитать ещё 25 раз.

Comment: Вопрос, конечно, не по теме, но очень интересно - а как в других языках, например, ruby? Там блокируется исполнение?

Comment: у всех по-разному. нужно спрашивать специалистов каждого языка (ты [знаешь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) что делать)

Comment: если в основе языка/технологии не лежит событийная машина то там другой подход